# ANDing / ORing / grouping query filters in Slick

Tags: slick

Given a table which stores a nullable expiration date, I want to find all records with either (1) a null expiration date or (2) a not-yet-passed expiration date. What I've got so far is:

```
val results = Query(TableClass)
  .filter(_.expires > new Timestamp(DateTime.now().getMillis()))
  .list
```

which finds all the records with current expiration dates, but misses all the records with null dates. How can I tell Slick this filter should only apply to non-null records? There don't seem to be any logical operators or grouping constructs in `ColumnExtensionMethods`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val results = Query(TableClass)
  .filter(r => r.isNull || r.expires > new Timestamp(DateTime.now().getMillis()))
  .list
```

https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/lifted/ExtensionMethods.scala#L104